# How to place mouse cursor to certain input box

Tags: php, html, input, cursor

How can I place the cursor automaticly to certain input box. This would help to not use the mouse all the time when open the page. (php and html)

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<input name="input1" id="input1" value="" />

window.onload = init;

function init(){
document.getElementById("input1").focus();
}
```

This should do

Comment: you should keep your opening brace on the same line as the function init()

Comment: I should indeed, but this way it looks easier to handle when dealing with large chunks of code, anyways I fixed it :)

Comment: c0mrade: What was up with your other answer? Why was it deleted?

Comment: Umm it was deleted because it was duplicate, I don't even know why there were 2 posts, I only wrote one .. they must have had some kind of glitch with the website at that time .. Jeff himself deleted it, maybe they figured out what was the prob.

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById("InputBoxID").focus();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `focus()` method of the input on `body.onLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" name="FirstName"/>
```

> Text Field Get Focused When Page Gets Loaded..

For More Info, Check This [Autofocus-Attribute](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/html5/autofocus-attribute.html) Link